# When to use CallNonvirtualObjectMethod and its related methods?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

It seems like `CallStaticObjectMethod`, `CallObjectMethodMethod` and etc... are all you need. According to the docs

> `CallNonvirtual<type>Method` families of routines and the `Call<type>Method` families of routines are different. `Call<type>Method` routines invoke the method based on the class of the object, while `CallNonvirtual<type>Method` routines invoke the method based on the class, designated by the `clazz` parameter, from which the method ID is obtained. The method ID must be obtained from the real class of the object or from one of its superclasses.

From that description it also sounds that the specific method `CallNonvirtualObjectMethod` has no use.

Comment: What's the JNI equivalent of `void someMethod() {super.someMethod();}`?

Comment: to call super I was thinking along the lines of FindClass("com.whatever.superclass"), GetMethodId(), then the regular Call<Type>Method? I never needed to do that though. If what you say is it, the documentation should really say "call super class" instead of the strange wording they have. Perhaps you should make that an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the documentation says, `Call<Type>Method` calls the method in the object's actual class, while `CallNonvirtual<Type>Method` calls the method in the class you specify.

Consider this Java code:

```
public class A {
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("A.doSomething " + this.getClass().getName());
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("B.doSomething " + this.getClass().getName());
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static native jniTest(B b);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B obj = new B();
        jniTest(obj);
    }
}
```

If `jniTest` tries to call `doSomething` on its parameter using `CallVoidMethod`, it will print "B.doSomething B". If it uses `CallNonvirtualVoidMethod`, it will print "A.doSomething B".

This is the same mechanism used for `super.` calls in Java (by the `invokespecial` bytecode); however, it is not restricted to calling methods in the current class's immediate superclass - you can't do `super.super.something()` or `new B().super.doSomething()` in Java, but you can with JNI.